# Is there a way to replace the intro screens?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm referring to the loading screens showing when the whole game is starting up.

I much preferred the ones in the base game and G&K, but now that I have BNW, I can't see the old ones any more. Is there any way to replace the BNW ones with those?

Comment: You can disable the Brave New Wold DLC in the Steam client so the old ones show up again, but that will disable all of the DLC's added content. Hmm... you could then take screenshots of the old intros, print them out, re-enable the DLC and then hold the print outs up in front of the screen when starting the game.

Comment: I know I could disable it, but I want the content, just not the screens. I hoped there would be a similar way to replace them to how I managed to replace the BNW into music with the G&K one, with just overwriting the BNW music file with the other version renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is not. A mod might exist out there but we don't support mod questions. Sorry and hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file

```
Loading_zh_Hant_HK.DDS
```

from the directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization V\Assets\DLC\Expansion2\UI\Art\LoadingImages
```

so Civ5 will fall back to the original file from Vanilla.

**I have not tested this!**

Accept this answer if it works, and I'll remove the disclaimer. :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. I tried moving the whole UI folder away, but still the BNW loading screens appeared when the game was starting up.

Comment: @kazerniel The G&K assets are in the `Expansion` directory under `DLC` whereas the BNW assets are under `Expansion2`, but I have no idea if installation order matters. Are you sure you moved the latter screens? This process worked for me with the loading video. Civ5 takes so long to load, but I'll try to verify this sometime today.

Comment: Yes, I removed the UI folder from under Expansion2 and it made no difference.